# Cannot set onClick for React

Tags: reactjs, express

OnClick's are not setting on my elements. I've looked at every tutorial and read every answer for the past week. Still nothing works for me and I have no idea why.

I've tried this
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html with no luck.

```
var React = require('react');
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';

class TableDataRow extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

    handleClick() {
        console.log("handleClick");
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
  }



    render() {
        // these are the same
        // const item = this.props.item;
        const {item} = this.props;

        console.log("test again");

        // this.handleClick();

        return (
            <tr>

            {Object.keys(item).map(key => <td value={key}>{item[key]}</td>)}
                <td>
                    <button onClick={(e) => console.log(e)} className="ui button edit blue" value="{item.id}">
                        <i className="edit icon"></i>
                    </button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button onClick={this.handleClick} className="ui button delete red" value="{item.id}">
                        <i className="delete icon"></i>
                        {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}
module.exports = TableDataRow;
```

Edit: both buttons do nothing on clicks. There are no logs sent to the server(terminal window) or browser.

Edit2: If it makes a difference I have React Dev tools installed but it does not show that my site is using React. I wonder if this means I have installed React wrong...or if these tools just don't work with w/e library I have installed.

Comment: Do you see any error? What's `onClick={(e) => console.log(e)}` printing?

Comment: Is the button normal button or have you used, semantic-ui button in your code, also do you mean, upon click, onClick event is not triggering

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca nothing at all

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri it's a normal button as far as I know.

Comment: Just a thought; Do any of the elements in the button's ancestry have css rule: `pointer-events: none`?

Comment: Why do you have `value` prop passed to button? Are you sure you are actually rendering this view? Why don't you remove everything from render and add a single button with **nothing** but a label. Can you see it? If so, then add a simple onClick prop that console logs something. Let me know.

Comment: @KyleRichardson hmm it's possible but I just removed all css classes and still no luck.

Comment: @nbkhope I will need to pass the value back to the server for on delete and on edit...maybe i could put it in the row, but for now on the button is easier. Yes, it is rendering but onClick does not console log anything

Comment: @TrevorWood (1) you can always pass arguments to the onClick event method handler, like so: `onClick={event => this.onSomethingClick(event, someValueHere)}`. (2) Did you try creating a new app using `create-react-app` and making a button there? Does that work? I think something is terribly wrong with your development environment. Without the context of how your file is included, we can't do much.

Comment: You may have some invisible DOM element over your button.

Comment: Can you try removing as much DOM as you can?